# Por qué no funciona mi función edit laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

espero me puedan ayudar.

tengo este query:

```
$cierre = DB::table('cierre_diario as cd')
                ->join('tipo_documento as td','cd.id_tipo_doc','=','td.id_tipo_doc')
                ->select('id_cierre_diario','td.id_tipo_doc','td.descripcion as tipo','documento','fecha','depositado','observaciones','cd.activo','cd.created_at')
                ->where('id_cierre_diario','=',$id)
                ->get();
```

cuando uso un dd(cierre) aparece esto:

```
Collection {#429 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#437 ▼
      +"id_cierre_diario": 4
      +"id_tipo_doc": 2
      +"tipo": "Recibo"
      +"documento": null
      +"fecha": "2020-09-17"
      +"depositado": null
      +"observaciones": null
      +"activo": 0
      +"created_at": "2020-09-20 17:36:08"
    }
  ]
}
```

pero si lo tiro a la vista aparece esto:

```
Property [id_cierre_diario] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /htdocs/app/resources/views/Cierres/edit.blade.php)
```

esta es mi vista:

```
@foreach ($cierre as $cie)
                      <tr><td>ID</td><td>{{ $cie->id_cierre_diario }}</td></tr> 
                        <tr><td>Fecha</td><td>{{ $cie->fecha }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Tipo de Documento</td><td>{{ $cie->tipo }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Documento</td><td>{{ $cie->documento }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Depositado</td><td>{{ $cie->depositado }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Observaciones</td><td>{{ $cie->observaciones }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td><label for="activo">Cierre</label></td><td>
                        @if ($cie->activo == 1)<input type="checkbox" name="activo" checked="">
                        @else <input type="checkbox" name="activo" {{ old('activo') ? 'checked' : '' }} >
                        @endif</td></tr>
                    @endforeach
```

allí me devuelve el ID.
pero si le coloco el form:

```
<form action="/cierre/{{$cierre->id_cierre_diario}}" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
```

no funciona, me podrían ayudar?
Gracias.

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu post, la variable *$cierre* es un array compuesto de objetos (uno en este caso). Prueba a poner en el form *$cierre[0]->id_cierre_diario*

Comment: Quieres un objeto, no una colección, termina tu consulta con `->first()` en lugar de `->get()`

Comment: No, sigue apareciendo lo mismo, si uso el firts o get